# Creating text files, appending them to zip, then delete them

Tags: python, zip

I am trying to get the code below to read the file `raw.txt`, split it by lines and save every individual line as a `.txt` file. I then want to append every text file to `splits.zip`, and delete them after appending so that the only thing remaining when the process is done is the `splits.zip`, which can then be moved elsewhere to be unzipped. With the current code, I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last): File "/Users/Simon/PycharmProjects/text-tools/file-splitter-txt.p‌​y",
line 13, in <module> at stonehenge summoning the all father. z.write(new_file) 
File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.12_2/Frameworks/Python.framewo‌​rk/Versions/2.7/lib/‌​python2.7/zipfile.py‌​", line 1123, in write st = os.stat(filename) TypeError: coercing to Unicode: need string or buffer,
file found
```

My code:

```
import zipfile
import os

z = zipfile.ZipFile("splits.zip", "w")
count = 0
with open('raw.txt','r') as infile:
    for line in infile:
        print line
        count +=1
        with open(str(count) + '.txt','w') as new_file:
            new_file.write(str(line))
        z.write(new_file)
        os.remove(new_file)
```

Comment: What is the full traceback?

Comment: `Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/Simon/PycharmProjects/text-tools/file-splitter-txt.py", line 13, in <module>
at stonehenge summoning the all father.
    z.write(new_file)

  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.12_2/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/zipfile.py", line 1123, in write
    st = os.stat(filename)
TypeError: coercing to Unicode: need string or buffer, file found`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could simply use [writestr](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/zipfile.html#zipfile.ZipFile.writestr) to write a string directly into the zipFile. For example:

```
zf.writestr(str(count) + '.txt', str(line), compress_type=...)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the file name like below. `write` method expects the filename and `remove` expects path. But you have given the file (`file_name`)

```
z.write(str(count) + '.txt')
os.remove(str(count) + '.txt')
```